# upgrading kafka 0.8.0 to 0.9.0

Tags: java, apache-kafka

In kafka 0.8.0 version, i used to create topics with the below command

```
./kafka_2.8.0-0.8.0/bin/kafka-create-topic.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replica 1 --partition 10 --replica-assignment-list 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 --topic unified-events
```

In kafak 0.9.0 version, I used the following command but it was not working

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --partitions 10 --replication-factor 1 --replica-assignment 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 --topic unified-events6

Option "[replica-assignment]" can't be used with option"[partitions]"
```

How to use the --replica-assignment-list  in kafka 0.9.0?

Answer (score 0):

kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replica-assignment 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 --topic unified-events

This command worked for me to create partitions on both brokers with respective ID.